# graph of D3.js cannot be updated

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to add line to graph of D3.js which is written already on the browser.

However, it is not updated. Please, help me.

--This is my code. The problem is 58-61 line.
----https://jsfiddle.net/ypmg8q4t/

--My code is made from this sample.
----https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/network_basic.html

I read this 2 pages to understand updating but I cannot figure out what should I do.
--http://bl.ocks.org/alansmithy/e984477a741bc56db5a5
--https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/

Answer (score 0):

*I'm assuming you're familiar with basic JavaScript and the DOM.*

## Understanding the data join

When appending to your chart, I'll try to describe what's happening, but in a way you might not expect. The key thing to keep is mind is that we will run this code **multiple times**, after modifying the data. This is how we deal with new elements in the data.

```js
svg
.selectAll("line") // 1.
.data(link_set)    // 2.
.enter()           // 3.
.append("line");
```

1. We create an object containing all line elements: a *selection*, a core concept which D3 manipulates. When you are using D3, you don't manipulate the DOM directly. You are acting on these **abstract representations** of the DOM which are these selections. The parent of this empty selection is the SVG.
2. Create the [data join](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/). The selection returned by 1. is *empty*. When we use data(), we *join* it to the passed data. This results in three selections. Wait, what?

That's a lot, so let's backtrack a bit:

- A selection is **not** a DOM element. A selection is an abstraction that represents DOM elements.
- With d3, you act on selections. Instead of mutating the DOM directly, you manipulate these selections.

3. When we do the [data join](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/), D3 returns three selections:

- the enter selection: elements that were in the data but not in the DOM.
- the update selection: elements that were in the data and the DOM, but whose values have changed.
- the exit selections: elements who are no longer in the data but in the DOM.

Let's say we have 3 elements: `[1,2,3]` Then the first time we run this code:

```
DOM : empty

       x x x
data: [1,2,3]

enter  selection: 3 elements (1,2,3)
update selection: empty
exit   selection: empty
```

But let's say we run this code a second time. DOM elements will already exist at that point, so what does it look like?

```
DOM :  line line line
       |    |    |
       |    |    |
data: [1,   2,   3]
enter  selection: empty
update selection: empty
exit   selection: empty
```

Let's run your code a third time, but adding some new elements:

```
DOM :  line line line
       |    |    |
       |    |    |    x
data: [1,   2,   3,   4]
enter  selection: 1 element (4)
update selection: empty
exit   selection: empty
```

Now there's some new data. **Only this new element is manipulated by the code. All actions afterwards, like the append, happen only on the new data**.

## How to implement this in your code?

To sum it up, if you want to update multiple times, then call the same code with different data. The usual way is to put the code in a function, with data as a parameter:

```js
function update(data) {
  // Put all chart drawing code here.
  svg
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(link_set)    
    .enter()           
    .append("line");
}
```

What's important to recognize is that this function will be called in all scenarios. It will be called for the first render with the initial data, and afterwards when the data is changed. You'll want to put all your chart drawing code in this function.

Most importantly, because of what we described earlier, this code will always work. In other words:

- your code was procedural: draw the lines, update data, draw them again.
- D3 code is declarative: tell the code once what happens when we add/update/remove data, then call that code every time we want and D3 takes care of it.

This is the core principle behind the **data join.**

Its usage might look like this:

```js
// Initial render.
data = [1,2,3]
update(data)
// Update data
data.push(4)
update(data)
```

Note that our example only manages adding elements. If you need to update or remove elements, you'll need handlers for those too, on every single selection. [You might look at using the join() function in this case.](https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join)